# JavaFX, embedded application in jsf page is slower than standalone

Tags: jsf, javafx-2, java-web-start

I am working about embedding a JavaFX GUI in a web application and I have this issue: the application launched standalone without using the jnlp file is faster than when it is launched by the web application using the jnlp file.

**Some details:**

- The jvm is the last stable 1.7u40
- All (also the application server) is running on my pc
- All used jars are signed by a certificate I signed using a CA created by my self using keytool.
- I set `<update check="always" policy="always"/>` on the jnlp file
- The download policy of jars on jnlp file is lazy

On the web I found nothing useful or explaining this behaviour. My suspect is that the jnlp start my application and something more, I will do some check about this.

I am open to any suggestions.

Thank you

**Update**
I found that the JavaFX GUI is slow only if it is embedded in the web page: if I call from the web page `dtjava.launch`(that executes the jnlp standalone) instead of `dtjava.embed`(that embeds the GUI in the page) all seams to work quite good.
The question persists why is it slower embedded?

Comment: Are you talking about startup times?

Comment: No, it's about using it: after the GUI is loaded, for example scrolling a table you see the scrollbar freezing for a second, when you use the jnlp, and not without it.

Comment: I have been using both ways for 1 year, but I didn't experience that. It might be a difference, but very small or close to 0.
Try with more browsers (but last version of all) to see if there's any difference.

Comment: I tried on IE, Firefox and Chrome: same behaviour.